# Report Builder: Add dictionary like page index in page header

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a report and I want the header to show details from the first and last record on the page, e.g. "Clinton - Fitzgerald" (as in a dictionary or yellow pages), so someone browsing through the pages can quickly find the right page.

How to achieve this? It doesn't need to be the actual page header. It might as well be a row in a parent group level that is repeated on each page...